# javascript regex for escaping comma and double quote

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to escape two special characters " and , in the string with the following rules.

Example:-

- Mercu"ry should be converted into "Mercu""ry"
- Mercu,ry should be converted into "Mercu,ry"
- Mer"cu,ry should be converted into "Mer""cu,ry"

Rules:-

- Meaning comma or double quote should be escaped with double quote.
- Comma will escaped by wrapping the whole word in double quotes.
- If Double quote is found, then it double quote should be added at its
  position. Also the whole word should be wrapped inside the double
  quotes.

Please suggest the regex pattern in javascript.

Comment: Does it have to be in one regex?

Comment: As stated, `Mercu""ry` would become `Mercu""""ry`.

Comment: Wouldn't it become `"Mercu""""ry"` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var test = [
    'Mercu"ry', 'Mercu,ry', 'Mer"cu,ry', 'Mercury'
];


for (x in test) {
    var s = test[x];
    if (s.indexOf('"') != -1) {
        s = s.replace(/"/g, '""');
    }

    if (s.match(/"|,/)) {
        s = '"' + s + '"';
    }

    alert(s);
}
```

Test: http://jsfiddle.net/ZGFV5/

Try to run the code with `Mer""cury` :)

Comment: Can you pls explain what is this pattern stand for s.match(/"|,/)

Answer (score 2):

Just always wrap the word in double quotes, and replace all double quotes with two:

```
function escapeWord(word) {
    return '"' + word.replace(/"/g, '""') + '"';
}
```

Comment: This solution assumes the string contains nothing but the word to be converted. This is not stipulated in the problem description. Therefore this will not work if the string has more than one word.

Comment: You're putting double quotes around word that have no commas or double quotes inside.

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression to achieve this is `/"/g`, so the following will work for your examples:

```
var test1 = 'Mercu"ry'
var test2 = 'Mercu,ry'
var test3 = 'Mer"cu,ry'

var regex = /"/g;

var example1 = '"' + test1.replace(regex, '""') + '"';
var example2 = '"' + test2.replace(regex, '""') + '"';
var example3 = '"' + test3.replace(regex, '""') + '"';

alert(example1 + " : " + example2 + " : " + example3);
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/Ra9JD/)

Comment: Same problem as @david-hu -- see my comment.